# How to get the last element in a sub document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is a sample mongo document i have.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("someid"),
    "doc": {
               subDoc: [{
                           content: [{name: 'aaa'}, {name: 'bbb'}, {name: 'ccc'}
                        },
                        {
                           content: [{name: 'aaa'}, {name: 'bbb'}, {name: 'ccc'}
                        },
                        {
                           content: [{name: 'aaa'}, {name: 'bbb'}, {name: 'ccc'}
                        }]
           }
}
```

I need to get the last element of the content which is nested array as mentioned in the above sample. I tried using aggregate with $project, still i was not able to get the result.

Expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("someid"),
    "doc": {
               subDoc: [{
                           content: {name: 'ccc'}
                        },
                        {
                           content: {name: 'ccc'}
                        },
                        {
                           content: {name: 'ccc'}
                        }]
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "doc.subDoc": {
            $map:
            {
                input: "$doc.subDoc",
                as: "each",
                in: { content: { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$each.content", -1] } }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0e6d1f400289966ece90d8"),
    "doc" : {
        "subDoc" : [ 
            {
                "content" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "aaa"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "bbb"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "ccc"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "content" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "aaa"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "bbb"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "ccc"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "content" : [ 
                    {
                        "name" : "aaa"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "bbb"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "ccc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0e6d1f400289966ece90d8"),
    "doc" : {
        "subDoc" : [ 
            {
                "content" : {
                    "name" : "ccc"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "content" : {
                    "name" : "ccc"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "content" : {
                    "name" : "ccc"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! This works perfectly fine!! Brilliant.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$slice` operator to get the last item from an array in the collection.

```
    {
      "$project" : {
          "_id" : 1,
           "subDoc": { "$slice": [ "$doc.subDoc", -1 ] }

      }

    }
```